# Dynamic memory allocation in C using realloc

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

I have read the other SO question about using realloc to get a new pointer to the beginning of a bigger memory address space but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. It prints a backtrace and memory dump.  I later try to access strhldr but I dont think it even gets that far.

```
char *strhldr = (char *)malloc(strsize);

 int chrctr = 0;
 if(chrctr == strsize - 3){ // when you get close
  strsize = strsize*2; //double size
  char *temp = realloc(strhldr, strsize); //make more room
    if(temp == NULL)
     printf("reallocate failed\n");
    else{
     strhldr = temp;
     free(temp); // removed same issue
    }
} 

// Later attempt to add it to an array
cmdargs[i] =  strhldr;
```

This is all within a while loop where chrctr and strsize get incremented

complete code

```
  int argctr = 64;
  char **cmdargs = (char **) malloc(argctr * sizeof(char*));
  char c = getchar();
  int i = 0;


  while(c != '\n' && c != EOF){ //read through a String of stdin
  int strsize = 32;
  char *strhldr = (char *)malloc(strsize);
  char *strstarthldr = strhldr;


    if(c == ' ')
      c = getchar();
    while(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != EOF){

      int chrctr = 0;
     if(chrctr == strsize - 3){ // when you get close
      strsize = strsize*2; //double size
      char *temp = realloc(strhldr, strsize); //make more room
        if(temp == NULL)
         printf("reallocate failed\n");
        else
         strhldr = temp;

    }      //add that word to the array of strings
      strhldr[chrctr] = c;
      chrctr++;
      c = getchar();

    }
    strhldr[charctr] = '\0';
    //strhldr = strstarthldr;
    cmdargs[i] =  strhldr;
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: Where is strhldr defined and set?

Comment: Does it ever print "reallocate failed"?

Comment: It prints the memory dump not "reallocation failed"

Comment: Are you sure your malloc succeds? If your malloc returns NULL...

Comment: can you compile it with -g3 and show us the stack when it exits?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value from `malloc()` in a C program.  You're not doing it for `realloc()`, so why the extra typing?

Comment: Could you please show the loop?  Your statement that "this is all within a while loop..." doesn't add up because part of "this" is the declaration of chrctr.

Comment: You check the error from realloc(), but you don't stop the code from continuing to (mis)use the memory if the failure occurs.  It probably isn't your actual problem, but it would be if you ever ran out of memory.

Comment: I have copied the code adding #include's and `int main() {` in the beginning and `}` at the end. For me it works. It doesn't crash at all.

Comment: Note too that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  If you assign to a `char` and then compare with EOF, one of two things happens, depending on whether `char` is signed or unsigned.  If `char` is signed, then a valid character (in ISO 8859-1, it is ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) is treated as EOF incorrectly.  If `char` is unsigned, no value ever matches EOF.

Answer (score 4):

On success, realloc will free its argument if needed.  So remove the call to free(temp).

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me what you are trying to do but I believe `free(temp);` invalidates *strhldr* and future read/write access to it will cause you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Second problem - your value charctr (not chrctr) is not set.  Here is a version of your loop.  I haven't tested it but it should be close.

```
  if(c == ' ') {
      c = getchar();
  }

  int chrctr = 0;
  while(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != EOF){
     if(chrctr == strsize - 3){ // when you get close
        strsize = strsize*2; //double size
        char *temp = realloc(strhldr, strsize); //make more room
        if(temp == NULL) {
           printf("reallocate failed\n");
           break;
        }
        else {
           strhldr = temp;
        }
     } 
     strhldr[chrctr] = c;
     chrctr++;
     c = getchar();
  }
  strhldr[chrctr] = 0;
```